# I don't understand what causes this to happen in Python with class

Tags: python, class

```
class Song(object):
    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print line

cheese = "Happy birthday to you,\nI dont want to get sued,\nSo I'll stop right there"

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around tha family",
                    "With pockets full of shells"])
Song([cheese]).sing_me_a_song()
bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

Here I'm talking about the `Song([cheese]).sing_me_a_song()` I made.

If I enter it as `song(cheese).sing_me_a_song()`

```
t
h
i
s
h
a
p
p
e
n
s
```

However if I put brackets like this song([cheese)].sing_me_a_song it is fixed.
What causes this? Is the brackets related to a list

Comment: This happens because when you iterate over a string, you get individual characters, when you iterate over a list of strings, you get the individual strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are *iterable*, just like lists are. You are passing in a *single string*, which can be iterated. However, when iterating over a string, you get each individual character, which is why you get your output:

```
>>> cheese = "Happy birthday to you,\nI dont want to get sued,\nSo I'll stop right there"
>>> for i in cheese[:5]:  # first 5 characters
...     print i
... 
H
a
p
p
y
```

If you expected there to be separate lines, then create a list with those lines:

```
cheese = ['Happy birthday to you,', 'I dont want to get sued,', "So I'll stop right there"]
```

or have Python create the list from the string using the [`str.splitlines()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
>>> cheese = "Happy birthday to you,\nI dont want to get sued,\nSo I'll stop right there"
>>> cheese.splitlines()
['Happy birthday to you,', 'I dont want to get sued,', "So I'll stop right there"]
```

e.g. pass the latter to your `song()` class:

```
song(cheese.splitlines()).sing_me_a_song()
```

Comment: What does "iterable" mean. I know it relates to loops but it wasn't defined in the book I'm going through and could use an example on the meaning

Comment: Iterable means you can iterate over it, getting the individual items out of it one at a time, such as in a list. Lists, tuples, strings, and dictionaries are iterable containers. You can also write other types of iterables that aren't collections but that nevertheless produce one item at a time.

Comment: @Lia: Anything you can loop over (== *iterate*). So lists, tuples, dictionaries, strings all are iterable because you can do `for something in iterable_object:`.